Converse of Intermediate Value Theorem via Nonstandard Analysis
I am working through Goldblatt's Lectures on the Hyperreals, and I am stuck on Exercise 7.8.4 (p. 82). It is a converse to the Intermediate Value Theorem:
"Let the real function $f$ be monotonic on $[a,b]$, and suppose that for all real $r$ between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ there exists a real $c\in[a,b]$ such that $f(c)=r$. Prove that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$."
Standard proofs are abundant. I am specifically looking for a proof using nonstandard analysis. For instance, for continuity I am anticipating that I will have to show that for every $c\in[a,b]$ and for every (hyperreal) $x\in{}^*\mathbb{R}$ such that $x\simeq c$, we have $f(x)\simeq f(c)$.
The notation $a\simeq b$ means that $a$ is "infinitely close" to $b$, meaning $a-b$ is infinitesimal. For the most part, Goldblatt exercises are short and sweet, but this one is completely evading me.
I've tried many things (both direct and by contradiction) but can't possibly include them all here. I can't seem to formulate a helpful statement to use transfer on. Say I start with $x\simeq c$. If $x=c$, then of course $f(x)\simeq f(c)$. So let's try the case $x>c$. By transferring monotonicity (assuming, say, nondecreasing), we should have $f(x)\ge f(c)$. If $f(x)=f(c)$, we are again done, so let's assume $f(x)>f(c)$. So at this point we could take an arbitrary $f(x)>y>f(c)$. By transferring the IVT property, we would get some $x'\in{}^*\mathbb{R}$ such that $c<x'<x$ and $y=f(x')$. This would imply that $x'\simeq c$, but I'm not sure what more this says. I could take a sequence of $y$'s that get closer to $f(c)$, but I'm not sure how that would imply the original $f(x)$ is infinitely close to $f(c)$. This is starting to feel like a standard proof anyway.

Let wlog $f(a)\ge f(b)$ and that $f$ is monotonously decreasing.
Let's assume $f$ wasn't continuous at some point $x\in[a,b]$. Then, for some $d\simeq 0$ we'd have that $f^*(x)\not \simeq f^*(x+d)$.
Let $\epsilon:= \text{std}(f^*(x) - f^*(x+d))$. Fix some $z>x$ (standard real). Then we have $z>x+d$. So, all together we get:
So we have $f^*(x)-f^*(z)\ge \epsilon$. Since $x,z$ are both standard we can transfer it back, but because $z>x$ was arbitrary, we can repeat this process for all $z>x$. Therefore we get:
$$
\forall z>x:\quad f(x)-f(z)\ge \epsilon
$$
and with that there can't exist any value $x'\in[a,b]$ for which $f(x')\in [f(x),f(x)+\epsilon)$.

Argue by contradiction. Assume $f$ is not right-continuous at $x_0$ (similar argument for missing left-continuity.) Then for any hyperreal $x_1 > x_0$ we have $f(x_1) - f(x_0) > L > 0$ for some fixed real L.

How do we get to say for any hyperreal $x_1$? It seems we can only say: $\exists c\in[a,b]$ and $\exists x>c$ with $x\simeq c$ such that $f(x)-f(c)>L>0$ for some $L\in\mathbb{R}$.

You will have to use the property of monotonicity.

So we get the existence of some $x>c$ such that $x\simeq c$ and $f(x)-f(c)>L>0$ for some real $L$. Monotonicity seems to tell us we can say for every $y>x(>c)$ we have $f(y)-f(c)\ge f(x)-f(c)>L>0$. I'm not sure how you conclude $f(x')-f(c)>L>0$ for $x>x'>c$ too.

You don't need that; ConnFus clarified in their answer.

Wlog assume the function is nondecreasing.  Suppose f is not continuous at some point c.  Then there is a point $c'\approx c$ such that $f(c')$ is not infinitely close to $f(c)$.  Assume that $c'<c$ (the other case is treated similarly).  By monotonicity, $f(x)$ will be appreciably less than $f(c)$ for any real $x<c$, and therefore no values between $st(f(c'))$ and $f(c)$ will be hit, contradicting the hypothesis.
